# lambdaJ and ClassCastException on simple select

Tags: java, classloader, classcastexception, cglib, lambdaj

I run out of ideas, Google also did not help. Use case seems to be trivial but it fails with ClassCastException. I don't know what I am doing wrong.
There's a simple method to return first element matching a given category, take a look.

```
private Category selectElement(List<? extends Category> results, Code code) {
    return selectFirst(results, having(on(Category.class).getCode(), is(code)));
}
```

Execution gives this top of the stack:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: name.wilu.logic.report.utils.SheetLoader$Category$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3a35aefc cannot be cast to net.sf.cglib.proxy.Factory
at ch.lambdaj.proxy.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:134)
at ch.lambdaj.proxy.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:101)
at ch.lambdaj.proxy.ProxyUtil.createProxy(ProxyUtil.java:52)
at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createPlaceholder(ArgumentsFactory.java:68)
at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.registerNewArgument(ArgumentsFactory.java:58)
at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createArgument(ArgumentsFactory.java:50)
at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createArgument(ArgumentsFactory.java:39)
at ch.lambdaj.Lambda.on(Lambda.java:63)
```

I had the same problem while using lambdaJ for manipulation over hibernate's persistent collections holding entities. I gave up assuming there might be some problem with proxying objects (entities in collection) that already are proxies.
It seems I were wrong because Category and all inherited classes are pojos passsed to the hibernate as a result transformer.

What might be a reason of such behavior?
Do you have any idea?

(I'm using the most recent lambdaj-2.4).

**Added to fulfill Mario's request**

Code is a simple enum.
Category is a base class for different categories, it has code field. Moreover, it's public static class, same as all inheriting classes (if it matters).

I'll try to provide failing test.

**Editing again to provide additional info.**
A friend of mine took a look on the code and put a fresh bright light on the issue.

I will try to reproduce our path of deduction from the very beginning.

*// Given*

There's an application divided into two parts, the first - base application (keeps model files) and the web application (keeps UI connected files like backing beans and so forth).
**Our category and code are model classes thus are located in base application.** We have then a backing bean serving for the purpose of some web logic and particularly **that bean or its collaborator calls our select.**

*// When*

We're deploying application to a web server! JBoss in my case. Classes are read by loaders, some pretty complicated things that I'm not aware of happen, all to have my application running.
I do some web action and **that backing bean's** method is called

```
 selectFirst(results, having(on(Category.class).getCode(), is(code)));
```

from web part of application.

Here comes the magic.
Our Category.class and Code.class were loaded by UnifiedClassLoader on application load.
We're in **on(Category.class)** method and the proxy of Category is going to be built. Some really tangled logic is harnessed to do that, What's the most important, proxy is instrumented with

```
setThreadsCallbacks(Callback[]callbacks)
```

method, but Callback.class is taken from that class loader

```
 aCategory.getClass.getClassLoader()
```

thus it is a class loader that initially loaded that class, the UnifiedClassLoader .
Having all this done cleanly we finally call

```
 getFirstInstance()
```

that using reflection browses Proxy class seeking for:
     Proxy.getDeclaredMethod("setThreadsCallbacks", new Class[]{ Callback[].class });

I omit the fact, I do not understand

```
 new Class[]{ Callback[].class }
```

What's important in our case is that Callback.class is NOT PROVIDED BY UnifiedClassLoader.
Applicaiton is executed in a web tire so a call for Callback.class will be server by web app. class loader and retured Callback.class will dffer from what was previously put as an argment for mentioned *setThreadsCallbacks* functon. Reflection fails cruelly.

```
Category.class != Category.class //these two were provided by different classLoaders
```

That is why I was not able to provide failing test. (same class loader).

I doubt there's any solution for that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered a similar problem. (The same exception thrown: java.lang.ClassCastException: XXX$Category$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$XXX cannot be cast to net.sf.cglib.proxy.Factory)

In my case it turned out to be a problem with duplicated (or even tripled) CGLib library. We had as follows:

- cglib.jar in JBoss (4.2.3) library
- cglib-nodep.jar in our application web-library (WAR file)
- labmdaj-2.4-with-dependencies.jar in application web-library.

Then, when using Lambda.on(SomeClass.class) we get to this method in CGLib's `Enhancer` class:

```
private static Method getCallbacksSetter(Class type, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        return type.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class[]{ Callback[].class });
}
```

where `methodName = "CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS"`
and type is our SomeClass wrapped by `Enhancer`.

"CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS" method was present in wrapped type, but getDeclaredMethod() returned null. It appeared that inside getDeclaredMethod() there was a comparison of two `net.sf.cglib.proxy.Callback.class` instances. And they were different since one was loaded from cglib.jar (JBoss) and the other from cglib-nodep.jar (webapp).

The solution was to delete redundant cglib-nodep.jar and replace lambda-2.4-with-dependencies.jar with lambda-2.4.jar. Now all CGLib classes are loaded from common place and the problems have gone.